# Can I print a photo onto the visa application itself instead of gluing it on?

Tags: visas

When a visa application asks for a visa photo, does it matter whether it's on photo paper or whether it's glued on?

If I can very neatly print my photo onto the PDF in the correct place myself, is there a chance they would nevertheless reject it because it's not glued on as they had expected?

Comment: It depends very much on the specific country. But in general, not following the instructions for a visa application is a good way to be refused and lose the application fees.

Comment: Which country are we talking about here?

Comment: @JoErNanO: Haha, I'm not sure I want to give details on that on the internet at the moment... but the general information I got below is still useful for my question.

Comment: there's a chance they may cut out or remove the photo for use else where.

Comment: In general, you should assume any and all instructions for completing a visa application matter, and not following them could cause delay if not worse.

Comment: In the UK, the application will be rejected (but not refused).  It's ok to use your own printer as long as the paper quality is up to scratch.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't see how the country could possibly be considered sensitive information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without knowing which country you are applying for a visa for it's impossible to answer this with certainty, however...

I suspect your chances of having your application rejected are extremely high. Ignoring the fact that you have ignored the explicit instructions for the application, photos (even those printed at home) are generally printed onto special "photo" paper, not standard paper.  Any photo printed on standard paper is likely below the standards that are set for the photograph.

For example, the [Australia photo requirements](https://www.passports.gov.au/passportsexplained/theapplicationprocess/passportphotographguidelines/Pages/default.aspx) state that the photo must be "Good quality, **colour gloss prints**, less than six months old", whilst [those for the US](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/photos.html) state it must be "Printed on **photo quality paper**" thus standard paper will not suffice for either of those two.

Many countries do allow uploading a photo during the (online) application process.  In this case they will normally include a copy of the photo on the application form, however this is intended more as a confirmation that the photo has been supplied rather than to be used in it's own right.  As they have the original (uploaded) photo, no physical photo is normally required in these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that in my case they say they actually have a photo service for people who don't have a photo or whose photos don't meet their criteria, so I'm guessing it might be worth trying since in the worst case I'll just have to shell out some money to retake it there, and it won't get outright denied because of this. But this is useful to know nonetheless! +1

Comment: Update: You're right, they said it's wrong to print the photo. However since I already had a photo on glossy paper with me too, they just took that and taped it (with double-sided tape) on where it was supposed to go anyway; it didn't get rejected or anything.